# Game Theory Schulz Method

Tags: game-theory

Hey I was wondering I did all the 3 neccessary things so Head to Head comparision,
Diagraph and the Head to Head Strength Comparision with the help of the Diagraph.
In first method there is no condorcet winner so I went on and did the graph with a,b,c,d,e
candidates and as result comes out that a wins all his pairs and d but when a and d compete they
tie who wins now ?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Append two blanks to a line you want a break after. Enable a spelling checker.

Comment: Can you edit your question such that it contains a complete example?